# Comparing two lists of strings and getting indices of duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I want to get the indices of the values (strings) which are duplicated. 
For example:

```
a=['iii','jjj','rrr']
b=['iii','lll','yyy','ttt','jjj']    
s=numpy.where(a==b)
```

I want `s` to return `[0,4]`, but at the moment it just returns `[0]` as this is where they are the same value and in same position in the list.

Comment: What is `where()` and where is it coming from?

Comment: Also how is `[0,4]` a more valid result? Both occur at index 0, neither is at index 4.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> np.where(np.in1d(b, a))[0]
array([0, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max` and `min` function within a list comprehension :

```
>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(max(a,b,key=len)) if j in min(a,b,key=len)]
[0, 4]
```